# how can I get the Freebase Easy dataset as one structured file?

Tags: wikipedia-api, freebase, freebase-acre

I downloaded the Freebase Easy [dataset](http://freebase-easy.cs.uni-freiburg.de/dump/) (3.3GB). I want to investigate this dataset in typing some entities. e.g: German  (types in freebase: location, country, land.....).
[image]

How can I CONCATENATE these three files to have full dataset?

Comment: Where did you download from? Those filenames don't look familiar as part of the original Freebase data dump from Google. Also, text would be much more useful than an image since it's searchable, can be cut/paste, etc.

Comment: I downloaded the file from this link: http://freebase-easy.cs.uni-freiburg.de/dump/

Answer (score 0):

The files (facts.txt freebase-links.txt scores.txt) are all in the same format, so they can be simply concatenated. On a Unix-like system, you could use the command:

```
cat facts.txt freebase-links.txt scores.txt > all.txt
```

or you could keep everything compressed by doing something like

```
unzip -ca freebase-easy-latest.zip \*.txt | gzip > freebase-easy-all.txt.gz
```

an example entry would look like

```
$ unzip -ca freebase-easy-latest.zip \*.txt | grep $"^B\t" 
B   prominence-score    1758.0  .
B   freebase-entity <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/m.0560cf>   .
B   Transit System  New York City Subway    .
B   is-a    Topic   .
B   is-a    Transit Line    .
B   kg/object_profile/prominent_type    Transit Line    .
```

where the first line is from `scores.txt`, the second line from `freebase-links.txt`, and the remainder from `facts.txt`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will check this method.